# Cannot Insert records due to Error code 1054

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I am currently trying to insert data for testing purposes into a table in a mysql DB. I entered almost 200 records but then i began receiving the error below.

```
INSERT INTO iwms.iwp_sensor_data
(`sms_sequence_number`, `leak_coefficient_avg`, `longest_prime`, `volume_0_2`,
`volume_2_4`, `volume_4_6`, `volume_6_8`, `volume_8_10`, `volume_10_12`, `volume_12_14`,
`volume_14_16`, `volume_16_18`, `volume_18_20`, `volume_20_22`, `volume_22_24`,     
`level_max`, `level_min`, `battery_percentage`, `iwp_pump_id_fk`, `date_sensed`,
`iwp_unparsed_sensor_data_id_fk`) VALUES (
3, 0.08887, 38.7738, 44.30071, 104.08921, 175.13669, 292.13478, 312.91996,
125.43943, 229.03636, 211.09809, 175.74070, 114.65359, 124.89872, 20.24331,
28.85225, 29.82441, 3, 2, '2014/1/2', 1);
```

I have not changed any of the insert statement columns from the first 200 entries. I actually just copied and pasted it while changing the values being inserted. There is also no "closed" column that i can see so i am not sure why it is saying that it is included in the field list. This is very confusing as there is no error thrown for the insert statement below, but the one above is getting the 1054 error.

```
INSERT INTO iwms.iwp_sensor_data 
(`sms_sequence_number`, `leak_coefficient_avg`, `longest_prime`, `volume_0_2`,
`volume_2_4`, `volume_4_6`, `volume_6_8`, `volume_8_10`, `volume_10_12`,
`volume_12_14`, `volume_14_16`, `volume_16_18`, `volume_18_20`, `volume_20_22`,
`volume_22_24`, `level_max`, `level_min`, `battery_percentage`, `iwp_pump_id_fk`,
`date_sensed`, `iwp_unparsed_sensor_data_id_fk`) VALUES (
2, 0.13626, 36.6522, 33.98187, 120.34705, 174.09935, 289.47317, 334.50053,
119.99472, 230.21259, 226.41231, 193.51348, 128.20923, 113.48517, 16.48767,
27.98960, 32.12844, 40, 2, '2014/1/1', 1);
```

Here is an image of the Table Structure.

[image: http://imgur.com/FsW3Ikq]

Comment: Show table structure for table `iwp_sensor_data `

Comment: I just included a link to an image of the table structure.

Comment: What is the complete error you get attempting the insert? Can you also confirm the query in your example is the exact same one you're getting the error on?

Comment: 1054 _should_ be telling you **exactly** which column it's having a problem with.  Given that the column lists appear to be the same, we find this to be suspicious.  Regardless, if this is the case, it's essentially a typographical error...

Answer (score 0):

Well, can't find anything wrong with the query text you have posted but in your screen print I see an extra column included `sms_message_text` which is not present in the insert query.